# Usage of a dictionary, Right or wrong?

Tags: python, dictionary, printing

I'm creating a car sales program and need to use a dictionary, I have a basic understanding of them. Would it be efficient to hold the car name as a string for the key, then store the relevant cars selling price in the values through a list? for example,

```
Audi1Price = 1000

Audi2Price = 1500

Cars = ["Audi": [Audi1Price, Audi2Price]]
```

Can this work? Is there a better usage for the dictionary?

Maybe there's a better way to work with the selling price as I'd like to print it out too, I'm unsure. Thanks

Comment: Your idea is sound, but you have a syntax mistake there: -- use curly braces instead: `{"Audi": [Audi1Price, Audi2Price]}` instead of `["Audi": [Audi1Price, Audi2Price]]`.

Comment: As for whether it would be efficient to hold the car name as a string for the key, it really depends on your data access patterns, which we can't tell from your question.

Comment: all depends what you will do with data. If you want to print by mark then keeping in dictionary. But if you plan something more complex then maybe use table in `pandas.DataFrame` or in database (ie. `SQLite`). They have functions to make more complex tasks ie. selecting cars in some range of prices or in some range of years of production. Calculate average price or total value of cars. etc.

Comment: @rcshon yep - sorry, mind went blank for a second.

Comment: @furas alright I'll look into pandas.DataFrame - Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that could work.

There is a problem in your example code, though: you used `[]` instead of `{}` for the dictionary.

You need to do this:

```
Audi1Price = 1000
Audi2Price = 1500

Cars = {
  "Audi": [Audi1Price,Audi2Price]
}
```

Comment: Oops yeah I didn't mean that little error, thanks. Okay, thanks for clearing that up.